# Free high-resolution Orthophotography for Quebec

Tags: canada, orthophoto

Is anyone aware of free high-resolution orthophotography for Quebec? Something 1m resolution or greater would be ideal.

I'm looking for imagery to use in a standard GIS as files (so not as WMS or other service, or via the web.)

Comment: What application do you use? Is Google Earth imagery not sufficient? Or BING?

Comment: Google Earth and Bing are both mapping applications, tied to their data. What Darren is looking for is a file he can download to use in a GIS.

Comment: 1m resolution for free?

Comment: Hi Mapperz. Valid question. I'm looking for something like DRAPE (http://www.mnr.gov.on.ca/en/Business/LIO/2ColumnSubPage/STEL02_168249.html) or SWOOP (http://www.swoop2010.ca/) like we have in Ontario. I'm aware these aren't 'free' but can in some cases be freely accessed depending on the client. I'm just looking for leads to something similar for Quebec.

Answer (score 1):

there is the ["Géoboutique Québec"](http://geoboutique.mrnf.gouv.qc.ca/edel/pages/recherche/critereRechercheEdel.faces), there you will find orthophotography from 15cm to 1m covering almost all the province. They are not free, it's about $50 a photo for example, but it's a very good quality material. The site is in french.

Au revoir.

Answer (score 1):

Orbview-3 1m panchromatic and 4m multi-spectral data is now [available free](http://www.vector1media.com/spatialsustain/usgs-now-offers-orbview-3-high-resolution-images-for-free.html) from the [USGS EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov). I just searched for Quebec and found 100+ scenes available from 2003-2005. It's satellite imagery, not orthophotography but it is high resolution. You can [pansharpen (or merge)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansharpened_image) the 1m pan and 4m multispectral to generate a 1m colour image.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try calling up a municipality or county and ask for their aerial photography. Where I work, we give out our SWOOP 2010 imagery for free but you have to sign a data use agreement. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: +1 - A good suggestion. I have gotten lucky a few times this way.  You never know until you call.

Answer (score 0):

You could try **[La Géomathèque](http://www.geomatheque.com/)** for Quebec Geospatial Data.

Comment: Can explain why it is the best site?

Answer (score -1):

**Landsat 7 Orthorectified Imagery over Canada**

*"The orthoimage data set is a complete set of cloud-free (less than 10%) orthoimages 
covering the Canadian landmass and created with the most accurate control data available 
at the time of creation. The imagery has been corrected with either provincial and aerial 
triangulation data or, if not available, the most accurate NTDB data. The objective is to 
obtain accuracy of 30 metres or better in the South and 50 metres or better in the North 
for a 90% level of confidence. The accuracy is evaluated for each orthoimage data set. 
The control data, which has been extracted from sources as mentioned above, can consist 
of road intersection vector data or lake/island centroids. In some cases the intersection 
of the centre line of surficial river may have been used. The control points are distributed 
homogeneously within the image in specific sectors. Sectors are located in the surround of 
the image, in the lowest and highest elevation area of the image, and in all other areas in 
which overlapping image base sectors are located.
The purpose is to promote the use of geomatics and educate by providing a Web and file transfer 
protocol (ftp) site that distributes Canada's geospatial data.  The objective of the national 
orthoimage project is to produce a complete set of cloud-free (less than 10%) orthoimages covering 
the Canadian landmass using Enhanced Thematic Mapper (ETM+) data from the Landsat-7 satellite. 
Production, which began in fall 2000, will span a period of three to five years.
"*

http://geogratis.cgdi.gc.ca/geogratis/en/download/landsat7.html
(global coverage at the 30-meter (98-feet) spatial resolution))

Canada in UTM or LCC
ftp://ftp.geogratis.gc.ca/landsat_7/ortho/geotiff/

Hint: '021L10' is Québec City , Quebec

Comment: Thanks Mapperz. I'm well aware of the Landsat stuff, but it's not very high resolution. Even the SPOT stuff available on GeoBase (http://geobase.ca/geobase/en/data/imagery/imr/description.html) is much better.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because, even though the resolution isn't nearly what you were hoping for, I've never had much luck finding better imagery for Canada -- especially for free.

Comment: Hi rmpeterson. The SPOT data I linked is actually 10m resolution. You may want to consider that over the Landsat stuff.